# Did Facebook change something about profile images?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-glide

I'm using the Glide library for my Android app in which most users have connected their Facebook profile and are using their profile picture from Facebook as their profile picture on my app. Suddenly today, without having changed any of the code, all images from graph.facebook.com aren't loading correctly with the exception of Facebook's generic profile pictures (what you will see as your profile picture if you haven't yet uploaded one). When I take the URL for the images and paste it in my browser, the images are now being downloaded into a file rather than displayed on the screen like they were in the past. Again, the exception is a generic image which will simply display within my browser like I had been used to.

Does anyone know if there was a change made on Facebook's end and if so, where I could find some sort of documentation of this change? Of course, I'm in need of a solution for how to actually display the images like normal again as well.

Here is the code for how I'm loading the image using the Glide library:

```
Glide.with(activity)
                .load(user.getProfileUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_profile_zero_state)
                .bitmapTransform(new com.zensports.util.views.CircleTransform(activity))
                .into(mProfileImage);
```

user.getProfileUrl() should return a URL like https://graph.facebook.com/1670580029918211/picture?width=700&height=700

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using an access token to access the pictures? please include the relevant code.

Comment: I don't believe that we're using an access token seeing as I'm just passing the URL to be loaded into Glide's .load method. I'll add the code in an edit for the question.